# Can't echo/exit/print a '0' string

Tags: php, echo, exit

The problem is pretty simple and annoying.
I want to print as response just a '0' string, a zero value, nothing else.

I tried with:

```
exit(0);
exit('0');
exit("0");
echo "0";

$foo = '0';
exit($foo);

exit(intval('0'));
```

It always comes out with a null response. The same on PHP 4, 5.2 & 5.3.
It's driving me crazy.

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php
die("0");
?>
```

Comment: How are you invoking this program?

Comment: And you never thought of `echo 0; exit;` ?

Comment: Welcome to PHP's implicit variable typing. Isn't it fun?

Comment: @onetrickpony not working at all!

Comment: What about `die("0");` (this worked for me) I noticed an (deleted) answer, but there wasn't any double quotes around the zero. Or do you absolutely want to use `exit`? @fillobotto Using `echo "0"; exit;` will also print a zero.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Neither it, didn't work. It's incredible

Comment: OK. Then it depends as the others have said, how it's being used/invoked. @fillobotto will need to see how you're using it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm invoking it from the browser.

Comment: I suspect there is a lot more code than just the exit. That will probably tell us the answer.

Comment: There is no other code... just *that* line

Comment: Tell us more about the system setup, are you sure you are actually running php?

Comment: Sure, all my other scripts are working. Again, echoing '1' is working, only zero gives me this problem.

Comment: @onetrickpony updated main post

Comment: Are you sure it's saved as a file your server is set to parse as PHP (i.e. a `.php` extension?) Otherwise, your best bet might be to view the entire HTTP transaction to see if you're missing something. (Also, I assume you have no caching, right?)

Comment: @meiamsome all PHP files are working so I suppose that PHP parsing is running fine. No caching.

Comment: @fillobotto all PHP files excluding the one that just has this in..? You sure it's saved correctly and has the right file permissions?

Comment: @meiamsome also that file runs correcty, for example if I output "1" or "bla bla". Just the "0" gives null response. I'm contacting the support of the hosting site. Please wait.

Comment: @fillobotto - check [THIS](http://3v4l.org/au2GZ) out

Comment: @aldanux This confirms that the real problem is my webhost (iPage.com). I submitted a ticket and I'm going to update the post when they answer me back.

Comment: unlikely. You keep posting the same code over and over again but you never told us how did you came to the conclusion that the response is "null". Do get a blank page in your browser? What if you create a new file and put the echo in it and run it in the browser? Do you see what you echoed?

Comment: @onetrickpony I know that since I'm performing a HTTP webrequest through vb.NET code and the response is a null string

Comment: Well, they just said me that it's an issue with their server (don't you say?). They could not give me any solutions: "you can print ' 0'...It's just the same". Honestly it's not the same to me.

Comment: @fillobotto Write your solution and mark it as answered since your issue was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was not in my pecies of code. I emailed my hosting support which could reproduce it successfully. The only way was to move to a different kind of output in order to get it diaplyed correctly.